# Calculate Area on a Map Using Overpass API Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to calculate the surface area of a building using the Overpass API, OpenStreetMap API, ReactJS. Here's the code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'; // Import Leaflet CSS
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.esm'; // Import Leaflet as ES module
import * as turf from '@turf/turf'; // Import turf library

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [buildingData, setBuildingData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // Make a request to the Overpass API
        const response = await axios.get('https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/interpreter');
        setBuildingData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Run once on component mount

  const calculateArea = () => {
    if (!buildingData || buildingData.features.length === 0) {
      return { areaSquareMeters: 0, areaSquareKilometers: 0 };
    }

    // Assuming buildingData is in a suitable format, adjust accordingly
    const osmCoordinates = buildingData.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];

    // Convert OSM coordinates to Leaflet-compatible coordinates
    const leafletCoordinates = osmCoordinates.map(([lon, lat]) => [lat, lon]);

    // Create a Leaflet map with a simple base layer
    const map = L.map('map').setView([59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393], 12);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    // Create a Leaflet polygon
    const polygon = new L.Polygon(leafletCoordinates);

    // Add the polygon to the map
    polygon.addTo(map);

    // Convert Leaflet polygon coordinates to GeoJSON format
    const geoJsonPolygon = {
      type: 'Polygon',
      coordinates: [leafletCoordinates],
    };

    // Calculate the area using the turf library
    const areaSquareMeters = turf.area(geoJsonPolygon);

    return {
      areaSquareMeters
    };
  };

  const area = calculateArea();

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh", display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <p>Area: {area.areaSquareMeters} square meters</p>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '500px', width: '500px', border: "3.2px solid red" }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

I'm expecting a map to show (id="map" container) but it doesn't, and the area outputs 0. I've figured out that the problem lies with the Overpass API Endpoint (https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/interpreter).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, _specific_ question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Component needs there change two items

**API Endpoint**: Later, you switched to using https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter, which is specifically designed for complex and extensive queries on the OpenStreetMap database.
And not `GET` , should be `POST` call.

**Query Format**: The query format in Overpass QL was likely enhanced to include more specific parameters, filters, or bounding box coordinates to fetch more targeted data like buildings within a certain radius.

More documentation in here

[Overpass QL](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL)

[Overpass API Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API)

[Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)

##### Wrong URL

```bash
https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/interpreter
```

[image]

##### Correct URL

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter
```

Body with `text` format

```
[out:json];
(
  // Fetch buildings in a specific area
  way["building"](around:3000,59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393); 
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

[image]

##### Demo component

Save as 'MapComponent.js'

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [buildingData, setBuildingData] = useState(null);
  const [area, setArea] = useState(0);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  // Initialize the map
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current = L.map('map').setView([59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393], 13); // Centered on Paris
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(mapRef.current);
    }
  }, []);

  // Fetch building data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {

        const response = await axios.post(
          'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
          `[out:json];(way["building"](around:3000,59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393););out body;>;out skel qt;`,
          {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
          }
        );
  
        setBuildingData(response.data);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const calculateAndDisplayArea = useCallback(() => {
    if (buildingData && mapRef.current) {
      let totalArea = 0;
      const nodeMapping = {}; // Assuming you have this mapping from node ID to { lat, lon }
  
      buildingData.elements.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === 'node') {
          nodeMapping[element.id] = { lat: element.lat, lon: element.lon };
        }
      });
  
      const features = buildingData.elements.filter(element => element.type === 'way');
  
      features.forEach(feature => {
        if (feature.nodes && feature.nodes.length > 0) {
          const coordinates = feature.nodes.map(nodeId => {
            const node = nodeMapping[nodeId];
            return [node.lat, node.lon];
          });
  
          if (coordinates.length > 0) {
            L.polygon(coordinates).addTo(mapRef.current); // Add polygon to map
  
            const geoJsonPolygon = {
              type: 'Polygon',
              coordinates: [coordinates.map(coord => [coord[1], coord[0]])], // Convert to [lon, lat]
            };
  
            totalArea += turf.area(geoJsonPolygon);
          }
        }
      });
  
      setArea(totalArea);
    }
  }, [buildingData]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateAndDisplayArea();
  }, [calculateAndDisplayArea, buildingData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Area: {area.toFixed(2)} square meters</p>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '800px', width: '1000px', margin: '0 auto'}}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

##### Result

[image]

The text **"Area: 303102.35 square meters"** represents
This means that the total area covered by the buildings or features you queried is approximately 303,102.35 square meters. It's a quantitative measure of how much surface area these buildings occupy.

Zoom in for seeing detail polygon
[image]

---

##### Update Component Two different color building drawing

the calculateAndDisplayArea function checks the building tag of each feature and applies a blue color for "office" buildings and a red color for "industrial" buildings.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

const MapComponent = () => {
  const [buildingData, setBuildingData] = useState(null);
  const [area, setArea] = useState(0);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  // Initialize the map
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapRef.current) {
      mapRef.current = L.map('map').setView([59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393], 13); // Centered on Paris
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(mapRef.current);
    }
  }, []);

  // Fetch building data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {

        const query = `[out:json];
          (
            way["building"="office"](around:3000,59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393);
            way["building"="industrial"](around:3000,59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393);
          );
          out body; >; out skel qt;`;

        const response = await axios.post(
          'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter', query, {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
          }
        );
  
        setBuildingData(response.data);

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const calculateAndDisplayArea = useCallback(() => {
    if (buildingData && mapRef.current) {
      let totalArea = 0;
      const nodeMapping = {}; // Assuming you have this mapping from node ID to { lat, lon }
  
      buildingData.elements.forEach(element => {
        if (element.type === 'node') {
          nodeMapping[element.id] = { lat: element.lat, lon: element.lon };
        }
      });
  
      const features = buildingData.elements.filter(element => element.type === 'way');
  
      features.forEach(feature => {
        if (feature.nodes && feature.nodes.length > 0) {
          const coordinates = feature.nodes.map(nodeId => {
            const node = nodeMapping[nodeId];
            return [node.lat, node.lon];
          });
  
          if (coordinates.length > 0) {
            // Check building type and apply color
            const buildingType = feature.tags?.building;
            const color = buildingType === 'office' ? 'blue' : buildingType === 'industrial' ? 'red' : 'grey';

            L.polygon(coordinates, { color }).addTo(mapRef.current); // Apply color to polygon

  
            const geoJsonPolygon = {
              type: 'Polygon',
              coordinates: [coordinates.map(coord => [coord[1], coord[0]])], // Convert to [lon, lat]
            };
  
            totalArea += turf.area(geoJsonPolygon);
          }
        }
      });
  
      setArea(totalArea);
    }
  }, [buildingData]);
  

  useEffect(() => {
    calculateAndDisplayArea();
  }, [calculateAndDisplayArea, buildingData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Area: {area.toFixed(2)} square meters</p>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '800px', width: '1000px', margin: '0 auto'}}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked on my end. Is there a way to make it so that it doesn't calculate the whole area, but only for one specific building?

Comment: You can specify the filter like "way["building"="office"]", "building": "office", "building": "industrial", "building": "container", "building": "warehouse", "building": "warehouse", "building": "garage", "building": "transportation"

Example in your POST data
[out:json];(way["building"="office"](around:3000,59.132659900251944, 9.727169813491393););out body;>;out skel qt;

Comment: This didn't work. I'm looking for residential buildings, and only the specific one from a certain address. Is it possible to have some sort of input where a user inputs an address and then based on that it calculates the area only for that specific one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated the color version. Try out!

Comment: I don't think you understood what I was trying to say. The building I'm trying to highlight needs to be the only one. I only need the surface area for that one. It's located at precisely the coordinates I have put in the code. However, your code highlights multiple buildings of multiple different addresses in the same area. The building is building number 54 on the map, if you can have a look at it. Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you separate your own seperate questions? You keep adding requests. It is out of my scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256758/discussion-between-david-guri-and-bench-vue).

Comment: Sorry, I have no time. It means make new question for helping other people.